# Having my own theme for creating and editing Nodes: No WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I disabled the option "Use the administration theme when editing or creating content" so I see everything in the default theme.
But now I got a problem: The JS Drupal object is on the bottom of the page (like in a usual page all JS files should be on the bottom).
But CKEditor (which I'm using) needs that object in head.

**//update:** I checked the scripts and found out, that ckeditor is executed on the very top of all scripts. The Drupal object on the other hand is on the bottom.
I tried to reverse the array, but still the same result. Even jQuery is loaded after CKEditor.

**//update2:** Okay I changed the order by putting weight on the CKEditor script files and set the scope of every script file to footer, but still the Drupal object is under all files, no matter what weight I give $js['settings']. Maybe that's the wrong item?

Thanks

Comment: try to add weight to the drupal_add_js() function. Visit http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330757/drupal-7-add-js-weight

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried that, but the result almost stayed the same. I'm trying again with the ckeditor files. Maybe this works better.

Comment: Okay, so this works for the ckeditor scripts, but the Drupal object is still at the bottom of every scripts. I added some information to my question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the weight did not work as expected I tried to set the scope for every script to 'header' except for ckeditor files. > **Did not work**

Because I had no clue I tried the opposite way:

```
  // Set scope for every script to footer.
  foreach ($js as $index => $value) {
    $js[$index]['scope'] = 'footer';
  }

  // Except for ckeditor files.
  $js_ckeditor_utils = &$js['sites/all/modules/ckeditor/includes/ckeditor.utils.js'];
  $js_ckeditor_utils['scope'] = 'header';
  $js_ckeditor = &$js['sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/ckeditor.js'];
  $js_ckeditor['scope'] = 'header';
```

**This works** - I don't know why, but it works.

Comment: Did you put this code in your theme's template.php file, in the wysiwyg module or any other place? Did you add it to any particular line or hook?