# CKEditor doesn't load when using Bootstrap theme

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I'm building a fresh site on Drupal 7.26 and the main Bootstrap 3 (7.x-3.0) theme from https://drupal.org/project/bootstrap.

My site also uses Organic Groups and Display Suite, along with many other modules. CKEditor 7.x-1.13 is installed. I have not edited the code of any file in the site, including the theme files.

**Problem**: When creating new content, CKEditor does not appear in the text area with 'filtered HTML' settings.

Details:

- My basic test user with only
  "authenticated user" role cannot use CKEditor to create or edit
  content. A Bootstrap-themed textarea is all that shows for all 'filtered HTML' text fields.
- My admin user, using the Seven theme in overlay for admin and
  editing, can access CKEditor everywhere I expect to see it. CKEditor
  buttons and layout are correct.
- I switched the site
  default theme over to Seven, and my basic test user could use
  CKEditor. Once the theme was switched back to Bootstrap, CKEditor
  went away.
- The really
  odd part: CKEditor loads properly for the basic test user in
  Bootstrap theme for all **comment entry** forms.

The only permissions I see for CKEditor are "Administer CKEditor access" and "Customize CKEditor appearance", which are both set only to administrator.

Resources I have read that are similar:

- [Having my own theme for creating and editing Nodes: No WYSIWYG Editor](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/70040/having-my-own-theme-for-creating-and-editing-nodes-no-wysiwyg-editor)
- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77731/ckeditor-doesnt-show-up
- [CKEditor is missing when editing a page, but works fine when creating a new page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79594/ckeditor-is-missing-when-editing-a-page-but-works-fine-when-creating-a-new-page)
- http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_for_Drupal/Open_Source/Drupal_7/Troubleshooting#CKEditor_does_not_work_in_my_theme

In the source code for a create node page in my basic test user's account, I see 
finally, at line 273 it has the scripts:

```
<script src="http://my.site.com/sites/all/modules/ckeditor/includes/ckeditor.utils.js?n1lvkb"></script>
<script src="http://my.site.com/sites/all/libraries/ckeditor/ckeditor.js?n1lvkb"></script>
<script src="http://my.site.com/sites/all/themes/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js?n1lvkb"></script>
```

I'm wondering if loading the CKEditor js at the end is related to this problem. Since I haven't yet dug into coding in Drupal though, I'm not sure how to correct it.  I'll be creating a Bootstrap sub-theme, and maybe I can address this problem there? Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

As I debug this, I'll add some edits at the bottom showing what I find.

Screen captures:
[image: new content as seen by basic test user]
[image: new content as seen by admin user]
[image: add comment form as seen by basic test user]

---

Updates:

1. I created a Bootstrap sub-theme and activated it. For a quick test I pasted the script sources for ckeditor into the head tag. In Firebug, when viewing a Page created by Panels, the console shows this error:

   TypeError: Drupal.settings.ckeditor is undefined
   window.CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = Drupal.settings.ckeditor.editor_path;
   on line 5 of ckeditor.utils.js

I guess that means settings haven't loaded yet.

2. I removed the pasted-in script sources.  After removing them, the above settings error no longer appears.  Based on the tips in the CKEditor troubleshooting, I verified that php commands to print the vars scripts and page_bottom are in place. Now, on a node creation page, Firebug reports these errors:

   TypeError: a(...).on is not a function
   ...a(this),f=e.data("bs.modal"),g=a.extend({},b.DEFAULTS,e.data(),"object"==typeof ...
   bootstrap.min.js (line 9)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.  The I am using the development version of [jQuery_update](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) which provides a fallback version of jQuery to use on administrative pages.  -- https://drupal.org/node/1524944

It determines whether or not to use the admin version based on if the current_path() is found in the return value of path_get_admin_paths().  Unfortunately for me,  `node/add` is an administrative path. So, jquery_update kicks in and loads jQuery 1.5.2 to be compatible with the administrative task. It seems CKEditor can't operate with 1.5.2. I noted above that CKEditor loaded without issue for a comment field on a node. Since viewing a node isn't an administrative path, the page was allowed to load jQuery 1.10 which works fine with CKEditor.

For now, I added an array of paths to exempt from admin status (node/add, node/add/post, etc) and added that to the evaluation in jQuery_update. Content creation pages now load jQuery 1.10 and CKEditor appears normally.

UPDATE: in place of the array of exempt paths, I have put in place the patch posted by muschpusch at https://drupal.org/node/2141205 . It has solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue with bootstrap theme..ckeditor not loading.

Turns out its jquery_update module issue which is loading admin version (1.5) in my case even when user is adding/editing nodes using our custom theme and not the admin theme.

Latest ckeditor needs minimum 1.7 version of jquery

patch here solves the issue.
https://www.drupal.org/node/2141205#comment-9260565